# Unhelpful error message when attempting to authenticate

Tags: support, feature-request, api, authentication, oauth2

I moved my app to a different server as part of a rewrite, and forgot to update the URL of the app on Stack Apps. When I tried to send a query to https://stackexchange.com/oauth and pass my (old, incorrect) callback URL to the `redirect_uri` parameter, this is the error I got:

> ### Application Login Failure
>
> An error occurred while login into an application.
>
> #### Error Details
>
> **error description:** Cannot return to provided redirect_uri

I’m still debugging, so I don’t know for sure that that was the issue, but either way, this error message could be a lot more helpful. I don’t know if this is the right place to file a bug/question like this, so I’m happy to post this elsewhere.

**Update:** I pointed the app at my new domain, and it’s working now, so it was a domain mismatch. I’m leaving this open in case it counts as a support request, because this took several hours to debug. Even after I had fixed the domain, I had a typo that meant I was getting the same error message. Just printing out the received and expected URLs would have made the problem instantly clear.

Comment: That message at least points in the right direction without compromising security.  Printing out the expected URL would be a security hole.  Maybe a message to make sure the two URL/domains match -- without providing details?

Comment: Good point. What about showing the part of the sent parameters that are wrong, and telling you what part of the configuration to look in to see if they match?

Comment: Might be good.  Specify.